# Visual Studio Code appears as a black screen when launching

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried installing Visual Studio Code in Different versions as well but every time black screen appears when launching instead of showing its contents.
I also tried using " --disable-gpu" at the end of the location in target. But that fails too.

[This screen appears after clicking the icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBuMY.png)

I also tried to install older versions of VS code but that fails to launch too.

Can anyone help me out how to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.

Comment: possibly related, similar, recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76728699/11107541